# Calculating minimum $l$ energy in central potential problems using this generalization of the variational theorem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, variational-principle, spherical-harmonics

The variational theorem talks about giving an upper bound on the lowest eigenvalue of a given Hermitian operator, and there is a simple generalization if we allow ourselves to constrain the space of trial functions:

> If  we can constrain the trial function $|\psi\rangle$ to satisfy $\langle \psi|\psi_{n'}\rangle = 0$ for all $n'$ such that $E_{n'} < E_m$, then it will follow that $\langle \psi|H|\psi_{n'}\rangle \geq E_m \langle \psi|\psi\rangle$. Hence we can calculate (or give an upper bound to) $E_m$
> by minimizing $\langle H \rangle = \langle \psi|H|\psi_{n'}\rangle/\langle \psi|\psi \rangle$ subject to the constraint that $|\psi \rangle$ be orthogonal to all state functions at energies lower than $E_m.$

In Quantum Mechanics: A Modern Development (2nd edition, page 296), Ballentine writes that this variational theorem enables us to give upper bounds for certain excited states:

> For a central potential one can calculate the lowest energy level for each orbital angular momentum quantum number $l$, with no more difficulty than is required to calculate the ground state energy. One simply chooses a trial function whose angular dependence is proportional to $Y_{l}^m(\theta,\phi)$.

Why does this choice work? If I want the lowest energy of an eigenstate with angular momentum $l$, $E_{l,min}$ then, per this generalization of the variational theorem, I must choose a trial wavefunction which is orthogonal to all eigenstates with energy less than $E_{l,min}$. Why does choosing $\psi \propto Y_{l}^m(\theta,\phi)$ achieve this? Is it as simple as saying that eigenstates with energy lower than $E_{l,min}$ must have $l' \neq l$ (else, since all central potential Hamiltonians can be taken with an angular momentum eigenbasis, it would be an eigenstate with angular momentum $l$ and an energy lower than $E_{l,min}$ , which contradicts the definition of $E_{l,min}$) and so are orthogonal to $Y_l^m$ by orthogonality of the spherical harmonics. My problem is that Ballentine explicitly says "whose angular dependence is proportional to $Y_{l}^m(\theta,\phi)$", rather than "whose angular dependence **is entirely equal to** $Y_{l}^m(\theta,\phi)$"? I'm also not sure my argument above is correct, so hopefully someone can clarify what they think Ballentine means as I think I'm not understanding something here.

I attach Ballentine's entire discussion below in case my description didn't make sense.

[image]

Comment: I may not be thinking about this carefully enough, but it seems to me that "entirely equal to" and "proportional to" in this case is a distinction without a difference, in the sense that any constant of proportionality can just be absorbed into the overall normalization, or into the radial part of the wave function.

Comment: @march I am worried that there might be some other part of the angular function, e.g. $g(\theta,\phi)$ for some $g$. Do you think this is ruled out by "is proportional to"? And, if so, do you agree with my argument to justify what Ballentine is saying?

Comment: Also it seems Ballentine makes an error in the inequality direction here right? It should be $\langle \psi|H|\psi_{n'}\rangle \geq E_m$ whereas he has $\leq$? @march

Comment: Yes, I think that's ruled out by "is proportional to".  For a central potential, the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian can be chosen to be angular momentum eigenstates, and so just take the angular part to be one of the spherical harmonics. But your argument is somewhat backwards. It's not about guaranteeing that every lower energy state will have $l$ not equal to the $l$ you've chosen. (This isn't true! - think about the hydrogen atom: each energy level includes an $l=0$ state.) Rather, you can guarantee that you get *some* higher energy state here (the ground state is only $l=0$!)

Comment: And yes, the inequality is backwards.

Comment: Would you be able to flesh out how my argument is backwards (perhaps in an answer if you have the time?). I don’t follow. My understanding is that Ballentine is trying to say that *if* we take the choice of trial wavefunction $\psi$ which is proportional to a spherical harmonic, *then* we will arrive at an upper bound on the lowest energy for a state with that same $l$. Is that not what he’s saying? @march

Comment: Oh I see what you meant.  I think I didn't understand what you were getting at in the OP.  So yes I think you're right.  The idea is that you will be searching for the lowest energy state that has angular momentum $l$. So if you set $l=2$ for the hydrogen atom, if you guess the *exact* eigenstate, you'll end up finding $E_3$, the third Bohr energy (because $l <2$ for the states in both lower energy levels $E_2$ and $E_1$).

Comment: I think so, yes. And even if we don’t guess the exact eigenstate for $\psi$, as long as we take it proportional to $Y_2^m$ for some $m$ then we will get an upper bound on $E_{2,min}$ since any eigenstates with $E< E_{2,min}$ have $Y_l^m$ with $l \neq 2$ and are therefore orthogonal to our trial state, which fulfills the hypothesis of our generalized variational theorem here? And also, this shouldn’t just be for hydrogen atom, right? @march

Comment: Seems right.  The choice of using $Y_{lm}$ is specific for any system with a central potential (like hydrogen), but more generally, this is mostly useful when you can take advantage of the symmetry (and the corresponding quantum numbers) of the system,

Comment: Thank you as always @march! If you'd like to leave an answer from what we've discussed I'd be happy to give it the checkmark -- whatever you prefer.

Comment: Just a note: It is even possible to generalize further, namely if you don't know the excited states (of course, under certain assumptions). See the Courant-Fischer aka Min-max theorem. IIRC, this theorem is discussed in Galindo Pascual, for example.

Comment: One day when I read GP I will encounter this :) my knowledge of analysis needs to get better first. Thank you for the tip! @TobiasFünke